# How to select Common rows from two different datatables

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatables retrieved from DB – which contain only one column(nvarchar(50)) each – I want to get all the rows that are common in these tables. I want to save the result in a new dataTable. How can I achieve this? Thank you so much in advance.

```
`DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    var FinalDataTable = new DataTable();`
```

FinalDataTable has to be filled with the common rows from both tables.

`foreach(var rows in dt1.Rows)`
tried to compare each row using

Not sure how it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
             on r1.Field<string>(0) equals r2.Field<string>(0)
             select r1;

var newDataTable = new DataTable();
newDataTable.Columns.Add("MyCol", typeof(string));
foreach (var item in result) {
    newDataTable.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
}
```

Where `dt1` and `dt2` are `DataTable`s with a single column of type string.

Comment: Helped a lot.. It gave me a new picture of how my code can use the different Dts to collate data.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void matchColumn()
  {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from images", "connectionString");

    DataTable DataTableA = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(DataTableA); // Fill the dataset

    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from images", "connectionString");

    DataTable DataTableb = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(DataTableb); // Fill the dataset2
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DataTableA.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      if (DataTableB.Rows[i][0] == DataTableA.Rows[i][0] && DataTableB.Rows[i][1] == DataTableA.Rows[i][1])
      {
        DataTableB.Rows[i]["Country"] = "Matched";
        found++;

        if (found >= 2)
        {
          //perform insertion
        }
      }
      else
      {
        DataTableB.Rows[i]["Country"] = "Not Matched";
      }
    }

  }
```

Try this

Comment: that looks great.. I will try this and let you know....